Same command running differently in Vscode terminal and Command Prompt
I am trying to test my node application and I have multiple test files so I used npm run test -- --test-concurrency=1 flag to test one file at a time.When I run that command in Vscode terminal the --test-concurrency=1 flag isn't set whereas when I use same command in command prompt it is being set.

What can I do to make it work in Vscode terminal?

In VSCode terminal you are running the code in a PowerShell console, not in the command prompt.
PowerShell and the default windows command line (cmd.exe) handle the arguments different and could even have a different path defined. You can try to run the same command in a separated powershell console (not inside VSCode and see what happens there).

Is there a way to make it work in Vscode terminal?

Try to set "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt" on the "settings.json"
